# MVC 4 Bootstrap carousel, images from a folder in the shared layout

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

I currently have a static slider implemented in a partial view under the shared folder:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_SliderPartial";
}

@*slider*@
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
            <img src="~/Content/images/ads/banner1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/Content/images/ads/banner2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/Content/images/ads/banner3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/Content/images/ads/banner4.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -> toont navigatie pijlen op slider-->
    @*                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
                    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>*@
</div>
```

I render this view in the _BootstrapLayoutcshtml which can be found in 
following pastebin: http://pastebin.com/AvxMeVQS (line 100) and it works perfectly fine.

My problem is that I want the slider to be dynamically filled with images stored in 
the ads folder based on certain parameters (I only want to displays ads that are active,
they all have a start and end date, stored in a database). I know how to code this
but the issue is that I don't have any controller (because shared doesn`t need one I guess?) to gather the ads and send them.

I would be amazing if somebody could help me because I am fairly new to MVC, thanks in advance!

Solution explorer: http://i46.tinypic.com/2cwt02h.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar, in order to follow a decent working practice you will need a Model and controller. You would probably want an Image view model for example (pseudo code below)

```
 namespace Models
{
public class adsImage
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string src {get; set;}
}
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{

public ActionResult RenderAds()
{

   List<Models.adsImage> imgList = new List<adsImage>();

   imgList.add(new adsImage({ src = ""});

   return PartalView("YourPartialView",imgList);
}
}
 }
```

Dont forget to bind model to view (add this to your partial view)

@model List

Last thing to do is render the partial view via your action method

```
 @{ Html.RenderAction("RenderAds","Home"); }
```